How do I package and install a released compiled version version of my .Net Framework? Do I just need to pass along the compiled .exe?
This might be a simple question. I searched online and there was a lot of information that seemed to be just a distraction. I want to release a .Net Framework C# Application that I have successfully built.
Do I bundle the contents of the Release folder or just the EXE's and DLL's?  Do I need to include the app.config and packages.config?
Do I need to create an installer somehow?
I have heard of Squirrel.  I understand that it downloads an executable from the internet.  I don't want that.
Update
Here is what I have done, as this YouTube video demonstrates (mostly)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5YlBv3dDlI
In Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 Click Project -->  Then click the project name Properties...
On the menu on the left, click "Signing" and click to sign the ClickOnce menifests.
Then click on "Security" on the menu on the left and enable ClickOnce security settings
Then click on "Publish" and then, what I did is select as the publishing folder to be a location on my company OneDrive.
And I clicked on Publish.
Then, as you can with OneDrive, I shared the folder with the application and setup executables with my boss.
But, in the future, I suppose I will have to use the FTP to do this.
I managed to create a Setup.exe through publishing but I do not know if this covers for the fact that the end user might not have .Net Framework installed on their computer. Does it?

@Dai, I will edit my post.  Thanks.

I managed to create a Setup.exe through publishing but I do not know if this covers for the fact that the end user might not have .Net Framework installed on their computer.  I will update the OP.

In the future you can also tie the application to a URL and it will check for and download updates from there.  You won't have to worry about the existence of .Net Framework as it's included in all modern Windows OSes.  (clickonce will also prompt user if they need an update if I remember right)  Each new publish will create a new folder in "Application Files" with the new version number.  You'll publish the contents of the "publish" folder.  (be careful not to publish the .pfx file as that would reveal your private key for signing)

@browsermator  Much thanks.  I gave you Kudos.
